# How Can I call Mvc Server Side Validation in Ajax call using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

**HTML**

```
<div class="portlet-body"> @using (Html.BeginForm()) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr /> @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Details, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10"> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Details, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Details, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="button" onclick="MainSave()" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" /> </div>
    </div>
  </div> } </div>
```

**Java Script JQuery**

```
var MainSave = function() {
  var Geturl = $("#hidUrlofsave").val();
  var Details = $("#Details").val();
  var Id = $("#hidid").val();
  if (Details != "") {
    $.ajax({
      url: Geturl,
      type: "Post",
      data: {
        Details: Details,
        Id: Id
      },
      success: function(res) {
        if (res == "true") {
          Loaditem();
          AutoLoader("Save", "success");
          $("#Details").val("");
        } else if (res == "update") {
          Loaditem();
          AutoLoader("Update", "success");
          $("#hidid").val("");
        } else {
          AutoLoader("error", "error");
        }
      }
    })
  } else {
    $("#Details").css("border", "solid 1px red")
  }
}
```

**C Sharp Mvc Action Code**

```
[HttpPost] 
public string ErpMainItem(tbl_inv_Main main) {
      try {
        if (main.Id == 0) {
          var ad = new MainRepoistory().Add(main);
          if (ad) {
            return "true";
          } else {
            return "false";
          }
        } else {
          var ad = new MainRepoistory().Update(main);
          if (ad) {
            return "update";
          } else {
            return "false";
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        return "false";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call only validation that are written in server side using ajax and doing so is also not a good way to go.

You can validate your model while posting form as

```
//Check if posted model data is valid or not
//checks every validation data annotation
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
  //<Model is valid
}
```

For the same effect (validation) in client side you have to include 3 files

1. jQuery.js
2. jquery.validate.js
3. jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

You can use minified version of above files but sequence should be maintained. After that client side validation is performed without sending data to server. You get all validation rules you have written in server side. Like *Required*, *MaxLength*, *Email* etc for HTML element that are bound to model properties.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Email, new{@class="form-control"}
```

Update

If data is being posted through Ajax and button is not type of submit then the form can be validated using .valid() function.

```
$("#postMyData").on('click', function(e){
   var isFormValid = $("#myForm").valid();
   if(isFormValid)
   {
    //Ajax Call
   }
});
```

Comment: This is working fine if use submit button instead using ajax call but when i use ajax call they d'n work fine they validate but the error message not appear in validation summary